# flutter/android: app freezes or crashes randomly when launching without throwing an exception

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I currently struggle with a flutter/android problem where the app freezes or crashes when launching. This happens within the authentication process and only when using the release mode (`flutter run --release`).

**main.dart:**

```
void main() async {
  print("called main");
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  print(Firebase.apps);
  if (Firebase.apps.isEmpty) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
  }
  
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _AppState();
  }
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  var isRegistered;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<bool> registerCurrentUser() async {
    print("start registerCurrentUser");
    final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final uid = user?.uid;
    if (getIt.isRegistered<MyUser>()) {
      getIt.unregister<MyUser>();
    }
    if (uid != null) {
      final DocumentSnapshot doc = await usersRef.doc(uid).get();
      currentUser = MyUser.fromDocument(doc);
      getIt.registerSingleton<MyUser>(currentUser!);
      print('user registered: ${uid}');
    }
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'audiogaide',
      theme: ThemeData().copyWith(
          useMaterial3: true,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
            seedColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 150, 2, 255),
          )),
      home: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.black),
            );
          }

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print("has Data");
            return StreamBuilder(
                stream: Stream.fromFuture(registerCurrentUser()),
                builder: ((context, snap) {
                  if (!snap.hasData || snap.data == null) {
                    print("no data yet");
                    return Scaffold(
                      body: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  }
                  print("user registered? ${snap.data}");
                  return const Gaide();
                }));
          }
          print("Show AuthScreen");
          return const AuthScreen();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The **output** given when using `flutter run --release --verbose`:

**Working Case:**

```
[+2749 ms] I/flutter ( 4574): called main
[   +3 ms] I/flutter ( 4574): []
[  +77 ms] I/flutter ( 4574): called main
[   +4 ms] I/flutter ( 4574): []
[ +829 ms] D/FlutterGeolocator( 4574): Creating service.
[        ] D/FlutterGeolocator( 4574): Binding to location service.
[   +9 ms] D/FlutterGeolocator( 4574): Flutter engine connected. Connected engine count 1
[        ] D/FlutterGeolocator( 4574): Flutter engine connected. Connected engine count 2
[  +32 ms] E/flutter ( 4574): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name
[DEFAULT] already exists!, IllegalStateException, Cause: null, Stacktrace: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists!
[        ] E/flutter ( 4574):   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.r.l(Unknown Source:9)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4574):   at x2.f.w(Unknown Source:54)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4574):   at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.i.u(Unknown Source:85)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4574):   at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.i.i(Unknown Source:0)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4574):   at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.d.run(Unknown Source:8)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4574):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4574):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4574):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4574): , null)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4574): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:189)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4574): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter ( 4574): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:96)       
[        ] E/flutter ( 4574): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter ( 4574): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4574): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter ( 4574): #3      main (package:gaide/main.dart:28)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4574): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter ( 4574): 
[  +31 ms] I/flutter ( 4574): has Data
[        ] I/flutter ( 4574): start registerCurrentUser
[        ] I/flutter ( 4574): no data yet
[ +400 ms] I/flutter ( 4574): user registered: WETlXVp8cSWQBVA8fDUTTqUeDbA3
[  +28 ms] I/flutter ( 4574): user registered? true
[+4467 ms] D/FlutterGeolocator( 4574): Flutter engine disconnected. Connected engine count 1
[   +6 ms] E/FlutterGeolocator( 4574): Geolocator position updates stopped
[        ] E/FlutterGeolocator( 4574): There is still another flutter engine connected, not stopping location service
```

**Freezing/Crashing Case:**

```
[+2719 ms] I/flutter ( 4656): called main
[   +2 ms] I/flutter ( 4656): []
[  +49 ms] I/flutter ( 4656): called main
[   +2 ms] I/flutter ( 4656): []
[ +157 ms] D/FlutterGeolocator( 4656): Creating service.
[   +1 ms] D/FlutterGeolocator( 4656): Binding to location service.
[   +6 ms] D/FlutterGeolocator( 4656): Flutter engine connected. Connected engine count 1
[   +2 ms] D/FlutterGeolocator( 4656): Flutter engine connected. Connected engine count 2
[  +52 ms] E/flutter ( 4656): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name
[DEFAULT] already exists!, IllegalStateException, Cause: null, Stacktrace: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists!
[        ] E/flutter ( 4656):   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.r.l(Unknown Source:9)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4656):   at x2.f.w(Unknown Source:54)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4656):   at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.i.u(Unknown Source:85)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4656):   at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.i.i(Unknown Source:0)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4656):   at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.d.run(Unknown Source:8)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4656):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4656):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4656):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4656): , null)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4656): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:189)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4656): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter ( 4656): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:96)       
[        ] E/flutter ( 4656): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter ( 4656): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4656): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter ( 4656): #3      main (package:gaide/main.dart:28)
[        ] E/flutter ( 4656): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter ( 4656): 
[  +62 ms] I/flutter ( 4656): has Data
[        ] I/flutter ( 4656): start registerCurrentUser
[        ] I/flutter ( 4656): no data yet
[ +317 ms] I/flutter ( 4656): user registered: WETlXVp8cSWQBVA8fDUTTqUeDbA3
```

**Further Concerns:**

The main() seems to get called twice, which also raises the PlatformException. From other sources it seems that the dependency audio_services is responsible for that which I am also using. Not sure how to fix this though.

**What I tried:**

1. Removing dependencies like audio_service and GeoLocator which I thought might influence this
2. Upgrading flutter and all other dependencies
3. Cleaning and Rebuilding the project

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is with Firebase I possibly try to use only

```
Future<void> main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
      runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

- Remove **print(Firebase.apps);** before Firebase initlaztion.